# InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnGetAsync(), Void OnGet()

[image: OnGetAsync(), Void OnGet()]I receive this error when building an application for .NET Core 2.1 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. This is the view I believe has the error within it. It is for the main index.cshtml razor page.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IList<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Customers = await _db.Customers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var contact = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(id);

        if (contact != null)
        {
            _db.Customers.Remove(contact);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage();
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Razor pages navigate using convention-based handlers.

The current PageModel has two Get handlers `Tasks.Task OnGetAsync()`, and `Void OnGet()` as clearly stated in the exception.

The framework is unable to determine which one to use.

Remove the `void OnGet` as it appears to be unused.

It would also be advisable to review the naming of `OnPostDeleteAsync` as this too may cause issue with routing.

> You can add handler methods for any HTTP verb. The most common
>   handlers are:
>
> - `OnGet` to initialize state needed for the page. OnGet sample.
> - `OnPost` to handle form submissions.
>
> The `Async` naming suffix is optional but is often used by convention
>   for asynchronous functions.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    private readonly AppDbContext _db;

    public IndexModel(AppDbContext db) {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IList<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
        Customers = await _db.Customers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id) {
        var contact = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(id);

        if (contact != null) {
            _db.Customers.Remove(contact);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }    
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }   
}
```

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages)

Answer (score 5):

For those using `dotnet watch run`, try restarting the app (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in the terminal).

I've had this happen after significant code changes. My code had a single matching handler, but .NET thought there was more than one before restart.

Comment: happened to me in vs2022 , restarted and it worked fine, hot reload doesnt seem to work well, using kendo ui as well...